# Simple node module command line example

Tags: javascript, command-line, node-modules

I want to make a simple node module that can be run from the command line that I can input files into, then it might change every instance of 'red' to 'blue' for example and then save that as a new file. Is there a simple example out there somewhere that I can edit to fit my purposes? I've tried looking but couldn't find one that was sufficiently simple to understand how to modify it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of `replace.js` (both old and new files are supposed to be in UTF-8 encoding):

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

const oldFilePath = process.argv[2];
const newFilePath = process.argv[3];

const oldFileContent = fs.readFileSync(oldFilePath, 'utf8');
const newFileContent = oldFileContent.replace(/red/g, 'blue');

fs.writeFileSync(newFilePath, newFileContent);
```

How to call:

```sh
node replace.js test.txt new_test.txt
```

Documentation on used API:

[process.argv](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

[fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

[fs.writeFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)